# Is it possible to add a tabbed page in a master detail detail page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail, tabbedpage

I need to make something like the picture below. Is adding a tabbed page in a detail page in master detail possible?
I keep getting invalid cast t error whenever I try. Help please 
[image]

Tried this code with webview but getting invalid cast exception

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Company.MobileApp.Custom"
            x:Class="Company.MobileApp.AboutPage">
    <Frame Padding="5"
           BackgroundColor="White"
           HasShadow="True"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           OutlineColor="Black"
           HeightRequest="80"
           WidthRequest="1000"
           MinimumHeightRequest="40"
           MinimumWidthRequest="200">
        <StackLayout Padding="20,5,20,0">
            <Label Text="Energy Comsumption" Style="{StaticResource boldLabelCenter}" />

            <local:CustomPicker x:Name="ddlPremises" HeightRequest="40" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>

    <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <ContentPage Title="Who is Company?">
        <StackLayout>
            <WebView Source="https://Company.com.sg/who/"
                     HeightRequest="1000"
                     WidthRequest="1000" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title="How to Switch">
        <StackLayout>
            <WebView Source="https://Company.com.sg/how-to-Company/"
                     HeightRequest="1000"
                     WidthRequest="1000" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. This works for me:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <v:OneNavigationPage Title="MyTitle">
        <x:Arguments>
            <MyTabbedPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </v:OneNavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Comment: Will this work in a detail page of the master detail page?

Comment: Oops sorry I misread the question. Can you update your question with your code which causes the exception?

Comment: I have made edits with code of what I am trying to do but tested the content of the tabbed page as webview. I am getting an invalid cast exception when adding the frame at the top.

Comment: Is it even possible for this kind of design to be done?